# $49 for a 2TB SSD?

Tags: hard-disk, ssd

This deal seems pretty unbelievable.
Any thoughts?

[GENSER-2TB-Portable-SSD-BlackExternal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09NWC4SF8)

Answer (score 1):

This seems too good to be true, so probably a scam.

Sure, SSD's are redicuasly cheap at the moment (<€90 for 1TB MX500), but good 2TB SSD's still cost more than €150. That GENSER comes with a €50 ssd, okay, but it cannot be more than 1TB.

Even if it reports in Windows as 2TB, it can still have a smaller size. Linus tech tips once did a video that showed a 1TB sd card that was actually 32GB, but still reported as a 1TB card, because the controller was flashed to report more than was availible. Get something from a reputable brand, so the controller reports less than is availible (overprovisioning)

Comment: I got scammed with a usb stick that reported 1GB, but was actually 250MB. The annoying thing was it didn't just "fill up" at 250MB, but each additional bit of data blindly overwrote and corrupted the previous. I check most purchases immediately with H2testw nowadays.